# Why is my Win32 application not starting?

Tags: c

I just made a C application (first time programming) but when I start the application, the console doesn't show up. However the program remains active in background because when I try to compile again, Linker says that it cannot access the .exe. 
The application runs smoothly on another computer (64bits and [Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows)). 
The app is ok but for some reasons my laptop can't run it.

I have a MSI apache 2qd (64bits). It runs on Windows 10 and use [Visual studio 2013](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx).

Here is the app source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>          // librairie de fonctions utiles dont printf() et scanf()
int main()                  // le programme principal, celui qui sera execute
{
    double a, b, c, sol, sil, delta;                // declaration des variables reelles
    //int i, j, quotient, reste;       declaration des variables entieres
    printf("Resolution de l'equation du second degre : ax²+bx+c=0 \n");
    printf("Terme du 2nd degre (a) : ");        
    scanf("%lf", &a);  
    printf("Terme du 1er degre (b) : ");        
    scanf("%lf", &b);                            // saisir sur le clavier : attention au &
    printf("Terme independant (c) : ");
    scanf("%lf", &c);

    if (a == 0)
    {
        printf("\nVous cherchez les solutions de l'equation %lf x² + %lf x + %lf = 0\n\n", a, b, c);
        if (b != 0)               // !=   est different de (comparaison ds une condition)
        {
            sol = -c / b;         //  =   calculer l'expression a droite et ranger le resultat dans la variable de gauche (affectation)
            printf("Solution unique : %lf \n", sol);
        }   
        {
            if (c == 0)           // ==   est egal a (comparaison ds une condition)
                printf("Equation indeterminee : une infinite de solutions !\n");
            else
                printf("Equation impossible : pas de solutions !\n");
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        if (a != 0)
        {
            delta = b*b - 4 * a*c;
            if (delta == 0)
            {
                sol = -b / 2 * a;
                printf("Solution unique : %lf \n", sol);
            }
            else
            {
                if (delta > 0)
                {
                    sol = (-b + sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);                                         // sqrt(x);
                    sil = (-b - sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
                    printf("solution 1 : %lf \n", sol);
                    printf("solution 2 : %lf \n", sil);
                }
            }
            if (delta < 0)
            {
                printf("Equation impossible : pas de solutions réel !\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;          
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: No one will help you out until you learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try to explain your problem in a detailed manner: what's your system version, what are your compiler and linker version, are you using an IDE (if yes which version), what compiler and linker switches do you use (i.e command lines passed to both programs). see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: try to kill the process in WinKey+R->"taskmgr"

Comment: I tried but the task manager doesn't show the processe and the only way I found is to restart the laptop.

Comment: Already tried. Unsuccessful sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off Avast or any other antivirus you currently have for a few minutes while you test your program.

Antivirus software sometimes get stuck analyzing this new executable and never return control back to the OS.

If this solves your issue, add your C projects folder to the exclusion list so you don't have to manually disable/re-enable the antivirus each time you want to run your application.

Comment: No problem :) When I started had that exact same issue, took me weeks to figure it out, happy coding!